# Trigger Jenkins build every 2 hours but only if there was a git commit

Tags: git, jenkins

Here is the problem that I am having - I need to trigger a job build every 2  hours but only if there was a git commit(skip if there was no activity). 
I can solve them individually but not sure how to solve them together - anybody has any good ideas?
The only one I can come up with is a cron job that would check every 2 hours and if there is a git commit during that time, trigger a job manually, but that does not look all that elegant.

Any good ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Set jenkins up to use the "Poll SCM" trigger every 2 hours (0 */2 * * *) or something like that

It'll update from git and, if there was a change, trigger a build.

Comment: It's better to use "H */2 * * *" to distribute load evenly throughout the hour.

Comment: I tried it and unfortunately (on **Jenkins 1.4.2 Core 2.107.1**) regardless of the GIT changes.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, unfortunately I haven't used Jenkins in several years. I would suggest posting a new question or asking on whatever forum the jenkins folks use to support the community.

Comment: i cant understand, if it is little more detail. it will be more usefull

Comment: I'm not really sure what further detail I can provide. At the time the answer was written the definition of a Jenkins job included a parameter called a "trigger", basically the criteria by which a job was kicked off. One of the types of triggers was "Poll SCM" it would Poll your Source Code Management system (a.k.a version control) for changes on a schedule, the schedule is defined using CRON's syntax. the provided example triggers at the zero'th minute of any hour that is divisible by 2, a.k.a. every 2 hours. Not sure if any of this data is still relevant since I haven't used Jenkins in years

Comment: @AntonioPetricca `I tried it and unfortunately (on Jenkins 1.4.2 Core 2.107.1) regardless of the GIT changes.`  It's not clear what this means.  This sentence seems to be missing a verb.  Did you mean `I tried it and unfortunately it failed`?

Answer (score 20):

H H/2 * * *

Poll SCM will occur at random minute every random intervals of 2 hrs.

Comment: This is better than using 0 */2 * * * since this helps distribute the load evenly, choosing random time withing an hour rather than setting a specific minute when build should start.

Comment: More info on Jenkins cron syntax:  https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#cron-syntax

Answer (score 7):

If you just set Poll Scm with cron expression H H/2 * * *, it will trigger the build for every 2 hours but the build will also be triggered if a git commit happens and it is not 2 hours yet.

If you check option **"Ignore post-commit hooks"** along with the above cron expression in **Poll SCM**, this will Ignore changes notified by SCM post-commit hooks and now the build will be triggered only if there is a commit and it has been 2 hours.

With this step you can completely avoid any manual intervention to trigger builds.

The help icon for this option explains its feature clearly as,

> This can be useful if you want to prevent some long-running jobs (e.g.
>   reports) starting because of every commit, but still want to run them
>   periodic if SCM changes have occurred.
>
> Note that this option needs to be supported by the SCM plugin, too!
>   The subversion-plugin supports this since version 1.44.

I have GIT 2.4.0 and is working fine with this option.

Answer (score 2):

Just set up the job to poll SCM every 2 hours.  If there was a commit in the previous 2 hours it will build.