# Upload last successful build to Fabric/Crashlytics with Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

I have an iOS app in a Bitbucket repo and recently made it working with Jenkins. It's a single Job, a build is triggered when a change happens in the repo, it's working fine.

I also managed in a post build action of the same job to take the path to the build and upload it to Fabric/Crashlytics.

My problem is, if there are 4-5 commits a day, each one will trigger a build, each one will be uploaded to Crashlytics and testers will be notified...

How should I configure Jenkins to run a daily job which takes the last successful build from the above project and only if that build is **new** (wasn't uploaded before) will invoke the upload script ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger Jenkins build every 2 hours but only if there was a git commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661301/trigger-jenkins-build-every-2-hours-but-only-if-there-was-a-git-commit)

Answer (score 0):

I think I've managed the above behavior with the following steps :

- The main building job triggers on a git push ( unchanged )
- I've added a new Archive Artifacts action which saves my latest successful build
- I've created a separate "upload build" job
- From the upload build job I copy over the latest successful build (with a plugin) into the second job's workspace
- I check there in shell if the copied over build's creation date is from the last 24h and if it is, I'll upload it to Crashlytics